# code suddenly appearing from my tempate second loop

Tags: loop, templates, code

Recently a client of mine has asked his host to host to a 'special wordpress' server. In the process a whole pile of errors have cropped up.

I have several templates based on this snippet of code. Its a standard loop, that then has a second loop bringing in 3 specific pages. This has worked fine for a year.

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
<div class="entry-content">
<?php the_content(); ?>     
:
:       
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php 
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type'=>'page', 
'post__in' => array( 5849, 6167, 6170), 
'orderby'   => 'ID', 
'order' =>'ASC' ) ); 
    $edcount==0;
     while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
         $edcount++;
        $query->the_post();
        echo '<aside class="herocolumn'.$edcount.'" >';
         the_content();
         echo '</aside>';
     }
     wp_reset_postdata();

?>
```

Now on the page I get the header, the first article but then this code appears in the body:

```
'page', 'post__in' => array( 5849, 6167, 6170), 'orderby' => 'ID', 'order' =>'ASC' ) ); $edcount==0; while ( $query->have_posts() ) { $edcount++; $query->the_post(); echo '
'; the_content(); echo '
'; } wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Which is part of my code in from the template. I have tried altering the format of my code, but can't see what's wrong.

Any ideas please?

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that you don't accidentally have a closing php tag where you shouldn't?

Comment: yes - turned out to be that I had <? rather than <?php - probably the new server was set differently - as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185320/how-to-enable-php-short-tags

Comment: Ah yes. Want to add the info from both our comments as an answer and then accept it? That keeps the site format tidy and stops the question being repeatedly flagged up as unanswered.

Answer (score 1):

Are you absolutely certain that you don't accidentally have a closing php tag where you shouldn't? – yes - turned out to be that I had `<?` rather than `<?php` - probably the new server was set differently - as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185320/how-to-enable-php-short-tags